# Error occurred while establishing Database connection in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify taht the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating Server/Instance specified)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you even tried to research this problem before posting the question? Try the following post: 7 things to check to resolve “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”:  http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the instance of the server is started.  Do this from Start Menu-> Microsoft SQL Server... ->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Services

If it is not on your local machine, i.e. on a remote server, then your account needs a login on the SQL Server that is granted access to the DB you are trying to connect to.

Usually the local server instance by default is installed with access for yourself.  But it doesn't hurt to check.

Also if it is remote, can others connect successfully?  If not, then you may also need remote connections enabled on SQL Server.

Making sure you have the name of the instance correct is important.  Slashes should be back slashes, not forward slashes.  What are you using for the instance name?